# Creating a html table by only looping columns

Tags: php, html

What would be the best way to create a HTML Table when I only can loop columns.

Normal a HTML Table is build on rows. And if I can only loop the columns I would need to loop the column in each `<tr>` and pick the field I want. I try to display that with this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>column1.field1</td>
    <td>column2.field1</td> 
    <td>column3.field1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1.field2</td>
    <td>column2.field2</td> 
    <td>column3.field2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column1.field3</td>
    <td>column2.field3</td> 
    <td>column3.field3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any other way I could do that without looping all the columns for each row?

Comment: you can build the table however you want, but in the end, the layout HAS to be row-centric, because that's how html was designed.

Comment: I assume your data is inside 2D array, right?

Comment: @Kasyx yes. It's a template engine, so I am not able to rebuild the array representing rows.

Comment: @nbar - thats bad. I was thinking about transposing this array. In effect you will be able to loop by columns. However show us example array with data.

Comment: tried a couple of things with css but couldn't get it to work, Javascript would get it though and I'd say if Jquery was used it wouldn't take long to knock something up.

Comment: @Billy thx for try. With JS it would be no problem, but I don't like to change so much with JS. In my opinion its much better if it comes correct from the server. I think i go with i loop all columns for each row